# How to call one function with parameter in other function by Python?

Tags: python, function

I know the title is a little bit confusing.

So let me take this code as example:

```
import timeit

def test1(x,y):
    return x*y

def time_cost(func):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    func()
    stop = timeit.default_timer()

    print(stop - start)

time_cost(test1)
```

I want to give test1's two parameter, x and y, to time_cost function.

But I don't know how to do so.

I have tried this before:

```
import timeit

def test1(x,y):
    return x*y

def time_cost(func):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    func
    stop = timeit.default_timer()

    print(stop - start)

time_cost(test1(1,2))
```

It can run but the result is so weird that I believe this is wrong.

So how to do this? Thank you all.

Comment: You can't give `x` and `y` as arguments to `time_cost` if it only accepts one agrument (`func`).  If you want `time_cost` to accept other arguments, then you need to rewrite it so it accepts those other arguments.

Comment: You'll want to read up on the terms: closures, decorators,  wrappers. The basic idea is that you replace ("wrap ") your function with a new function that does what you want and handles the arguments the way you want.

Answer (score 4):

Return a function that does what you want.

```
def time_cost(func):
    def run(*args, **kwargs):
        start = timeit.default_timer()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        stop = timeit.default_timer()

        print(stop - start)
    return run
```

Then call it.

```
time_cost(test1)(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try.

```
from functools import wraps
import timeit

def time_cost(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = timeit.default_timer()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        stop = timeit.default_timer()
        print(stop - start)
        return result
    return wrapper

test1 = time_cost(test1)
test1(1,2)
```

This kind of function is called a decorator. Also called a wrapper, or a closure.

You can also use this with the decorator syntax:

```
@time_cost
def test1(x,y):
    return x*y

test1(1,2)
```

This does the same as the code above.

Comment: Your method seems a little bit arcane. Whatever, I am really appreciate for  your help!

Comment: @MarsLee This is actually probably the preferred method for doing this kind of thing in Python. And it is identical to the first answer by IVA, I'm just using it slightly differently. See: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#abstract